# Replace while loop with for each

Tags: java

How can I replace while loop below with for each loop in Java?

```
JSONObject postParameters = new JSONObject();
Map parameterMap = httpRequest.getParameterMap();
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String[]>> it = parameterMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry = it.next();
    if(entry.getValue().length == 1){
        postParameters.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()[0].toString());
    }
    else{
        JSONArray valueList = new JSONArray();
        for(String value : entry.getValue()){
            valueList.add(value.toString());
        }
        postParameters.put(entry.getKey(), valueList);
    }
}
```

Basically I want to make it bit more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ForEach` directly on `entrySet` like this:

```
JSONObject postParameters = new JSONObject();
Map parameterMap = httpRequest.getParameterMap();
for (Map.Entry<String,String[]> entry : parameterMap.entrySet()){
    if(entry.getValue().length == 1){
        postParameters.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()[0].toString());
    }
    else{
        JSONArray valueList = new JSONArray();
        for(String value : entry.getValue()){
            valueList.add(value.toString());
        }
        postParameters.put(entry.getKey(), valueList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject postParameters = new JSONObject();
Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = httpRequest.getParameterMap();
for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : parameterMap.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().length == 1) {
        postParameters.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()[0]);
    } else {
        JSONArray valueList = new JSONArray();
        for (String value : entry.getValue()) {
            valueList.add(value);
        }
        postParameters.put(entry.getKey(), valueList);
    }
}
```

Exactly like Mustahsan said, but you can get rid of redudant toString() methods, and last `else` block can be changed to shorter version, think about collecting whole entry values at once and putting it in the postParameters as JSONArray.